# I want to form a group of order one, is it possible?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Can a set with one element be a group, or does a group need to have at least two elements?

Comment: Try defining a binary operation on a singleton set and see if it is a group.

Comment: The number $1$ is not a group. A set with a single element can be made a group, however.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Thomas Andrews. 

Can you explain how a single element can be made a group? By adding to it?

Comment: [“In mathematics, a trivial group is a group consisting of a single element”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_group).

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to have an element with just one element. Take $G=\{e\}$ with the group law defined as $e\circ e=e$. Then it is easy to verify that:

1. The group law is associative: $(e\circ e)\circ e=e\circ(e\circ e)=e$
2. There is an identity $e$ such that $e\circ g=g = g \circ e$ for all $g\in G$.
3. Every element of $G$ has an inverse, since $e$ is its own inverse.